# Reading JSON file return nothing

Tags: json, sql-server

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "isMoneyClient": false,
    "showPower": true,
    "removeGamePlay": true,
    "visualTweaks": {
      "0": {
        "value": true,
        "name": "Clock"
      },
      "1": {
        "value": true,
        "name": "CopperIcon"
      }
   }
}'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json) WITH ( 
   IsMoneyClient Varchar(50) '$.isMoneyClient',
   ShowPower Varchar(50) '$.showPower',
   RemoveGamePlay Varchar(50) '$.removeGamePlay'
)
```

The above is running fine
returning

| IsMoneyClient | ShowPower | RemoveGamePlay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | true | true |

However when I try to read from file using the following method

```
DECLARE @Scripts_Python     nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @json           nvarchar(max)
SET @Scripts_Python =
CONCAT('
import json
import io

with open("','F:/SQLFiles/pythonread.json','") as data_file:
    json_data = json.load(data_file)


json_output = json.dumps(json_data)

'
)


EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
    @language = N'Python'
    , @script = @Scripts_Python
    , @params = N'@json_output nvarchar(max) output'
    , @json_output = @json

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json) WITH ( 
   IsMoneyClient Varchar(50) '$.isMoneyClient',
   ShowPower Varchar(50) '$.showPower',
   RemoveGamePlay Varchar(50) '$.removeGamePlay'
)
```

It returns without error the follow table without the data

| IsMoneyClient | ShowPower | RemoveGamePlay |
| --- | --- | --- |

How to solve this?
Is this a accessing issue?

Comment: *open("','F:/SQLFiles/pythonread.json','")* ???

Comment: originally im using  @file in the place of 'F:/SQLFiles/pythonread.json'

Comment: it should run without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misdeclared the last parameter call, it should be @json OUTPUT, otherwise it just passes a NULL value without returning anything:

```sql
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
    @language = N'Python'
    , @script = @Scripts_Python
    , @params = N'@json_output nvarchar(max) output'
    , @json_output = @json OUTPUT
```

To debug these thing yourself, it helps printing the variables like @json before performing OPENJSON, to see that you're getting expected value

Comment: any recommenced guide book for using python in sql server ?